# "smooth transition" from differential graded Lie algebra to $L_\infty$-algebras

Tags: differential-graded-lie-algebras

Question is as in the title.

> When learning about $L_\infty$-algebras for the first time, is there a "smooth transition" one can make from differential graded Lie algebras to $L_\infty$-algebras.

The most general version of Lie algebra that I am comfortable in working is the notion of differential graded Lie algebra.

Fix base field to be the field $\mathbb{R}$.

A differential graded Lie algebra consists of

1. a graded vector space $V=\oplus_{i\in \mathbb{Z}}V_i$
2. an $\mathbb{R}$-bilinear map $[-,-]:=l_2:V\times V\rightarrow V$ (just as in the case of a Lie algebra),
3. an $\mathbb{R}$-linear map $d:V\rightarrow V$ (we do not have this data in case of a Lie algebra)

satisfying the following conditions,

1. compatibility of $l_2$ with the grading; $l_2(V_i,V_j)\subseteq V_{i+j}$
2. compatibility of $d$ with the grading; $d(V_i)\subseteq V_{i+1}$
3. compatibility of $d$ with $l_2$ (you know what this is)
4. "graded-commutative" property of $l_2$ (you know about this as well)
5. The Jacobi identity; that is,
   $$[x,[y,z]]+[y,[z,x]]+[z,[x,y]]=0,$$
   for homogeneous $x,y,z$ in $V$ (you also know that there are some signs missing here).

A $L_\infty$-algebra has all the data mentioned about and all the conditions mentioned above, except the last condition, Jacobi identity. As far as I understand, even though we may not have the left hand side component to be equal to zero, this is controlled by a nice $\mathbb{R}$-trilinear map $l_3:V\times V\times V\rightarrow V$ (preserves grading in an appropriate sense).

A (partial data of) $L_\infty$-algebra is given by

1. a graded vector space $V=\oplus_{i\in \mathbb{Z}}V_i$
2. an $\mathbb{R}$-bilinear map $[-,-]:=l_2:V\times V\rightarrow V$ (just as in the case of a Lie algebra),
3. an $\mathbb{R}$-linear map $d:V\rightarrow V$ (we do not have this data in case of a Lie algebra)
4. a $\mathbb{R}$-trilinear map $l_3:V\times V\times V\rightarrow V$ (we do not have this data in case of a dgla),

satisfying the following conditions,

1. compatibility of $l_2$ with the grading; $l_2(V_i,V_j)\subseteq V_{i+j}$
2. compatibility of $d$ with the grading; $d(V_i)\subseteq V_{i+1}$
3. compatibility of $d$ with $l_2$ (as before)
4. "graded-commutative" property of $l_2$  (as before) and $l_3$

For the last condition, we have
$$[x,[y,z]]+[y,[z,x]]+[z,[x,y]]= {\rm some~effect~ of~ l_3 ~on ~(x,y,z)}$$
To be precise, $d=l_1$ also plays a role in the above identity. We have
$$[x,[y,z]]+[y,[z,x]]+[z,[x,y]]= l_1(l_3(x,y,z))
+l_3(l_1(x),y,z)+l_3(x,l_1(y),z))+l_3(x,y,l_1(z))$$
Both of us know there are some signs missing in above condition.

This does not end here. The map $l_2:V\times V\rightarrow V$
gave the left hand side expression which is a $\mathbb{R}$-trilinear (I believe) map $V\times V\times V\rightarrow V$. We asked that this is controlled by some well behaved $\mathbb{R}$-trilinear map $l_3:V\times V\times V\rightarrow V$ (of course with the help of the differential $l_1=d$).

This trilinear map $l_3$ would also give a $\mathbb{R}$-4-linear map $V\times V\times V\times V\rightarrow V$ and it is expected that we would want this map to be controlled by some well behaved $\mathbb{R}$-4-linear map $l_4:V\times V\times V\times V\rightarrow V$ (possibly with help of $l_1,l_2$?)

This is where I am stuck in understanding how does one get that expression of "Jacobi identity" in the definition of $L_\infty$-algebras?

How does one reach that condition starting from the dgla point of view?

The condition I am talking about is

$$\sum_{i+j=n+1}\sum_{\sigma\in {\rm Sh}_{i,n-i}} l_j(l_i(x_{\sigma(1)},\cdots,x_{\sigma(i)}),x_{\sigma(i+1},\cdots,x_{\sigma(n})=0$$

Comment: This condition is just a homogeneous part of equation that $d^2 = 0$ in Harrison complex (i. e. Koszul dual cocommutative coalgebra). Data of $L_{\infty}$-algebra IS a square zero coderivation on cofree conilpotent commutative coalgebra; multilinear operations are just consequences. Also I'd recommend to NEVER omit signs in dg context, it'll bite you sooner or later if you do (speaking from personal experience).

Comment: Many thanks for the comment.. I do not omit signs but in the above question it would be disturbing to see so many signs :D Is it possible for someone to learn about $L_\infty$-algebras if they have absolutely no idea about what the words coderivations, coffee, conilpotent, cocommutative, coalgebras mean.. @DenisT